# Find all ascending triplets in array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matlab, combinations

I'm trying to exctract all the ascending triplets in an array of arbitrary dimension. For example if i have an array like `[1 2 3 4]` i'd like to obtain `[1 2 3] , [1 2 4] , [2 3 4]`

Here's a simple "graphical" example with 5 elements: 
[image]

The arrows are the indexes used to iterate, each step is a found triplet.

So far i've just implemented a simple sorting algorithm, which will give me the ordered array.

Once i have the ordered array, I iterate with 3 possible pointers (or just indexes) increasing the pointer starting at the third element until it reaches the end of the array.

Once it reaches the end, i'll increase the second pointer and reset the third to the position right next to the pointer 2 and so on.

```
array = [ 3 2 1 5 ];
array = sort(array);
//Now i should iterate over the 3 indexes, but i'm totally lost about how to place them 
for i=1:length(array-2)
    for j=2:length(array-1)
        for k=3:length(array)
         //storing triplet
        end
    end
end
```

Right now i'm able to iterate over the array, and i can extract all the triplets until the `k` index reaches the end of the array.

The problem is once i reach for the end, i have to increment the `j` index starting point and reset the `k` index to be right next to the second index.

To make it clear: right now once `k` reaches the end, it will start again from 3 and `j` will also be 3, but i need them to be `j` = 3 and `k` = 4 after the first iteration of `k` is completed and so on (this is valid also for `j` compared to `i` , look at the image for a clearer explanation).

How do i fix the indexes in order to extract the triplets correctly?

Comment: Post text as text, not images...

Comment: @Wolfie What do you mean?

Comment: The image you've posted would probably be much clearer if it was instead [formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) text, this applies in general unless your question specifically relates to an image! :)

Comment: @Wolfie Oh, i'll keep it in mind next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me like your inner iterations start one after your outer one:

```
for j=(i+1):length(array-1)
    for k=(j+1):length(array-1)
```

Generalizing the first loop to the rest.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arrayTotal = [3, 2, 1, 5];
let combinationArray = [];
arrayTotal.sort();
for (let i = 0; i < (arrayTotal.length - 2); i++) {
  for (let j = (i + 1); j < (arrayTotal.length - 1); j++) {
    for (let k = (j + 1); k < arrayTotal.length; k++) {
      combinationArray.push([arrayTotal[i], arrayTotal[j], arrayTotal[k]])
    }
  }
}
console.log(combinationArray);
```

Comment: Code without context is the mark of a low quality answer... moreover this isn't MATLAB syntax (per the question)!

Comment: I appreciate the full code, but what language is it?

Comment: It is javascript, didn't focus on the language as it was an algorithm question so basically the logic matters more here. :-)